# Push notification workarounds

Tags: cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I've been working to implement Firebase Cloud Messaging into our web based application. Currently we need to rely on loading this web based application inside a CEF / CefSharp based browser that we supply to the end users, and we've unfortunately found that the notification API is not supported within CEF.

Im reaching out to see if anyone has worked around this kind of problem before? My initial thoughts were to work on the ability to receive the FCM push notifications from inside our dotnet based browser and then pass these to the CEF hosted page via a javascript call. It doesnt seem like theres a way to subscribe to push notifications from dotnet.

Are there alternative push notification services that have a dotnet integration?

Thanks
Dave

Comment: You can write a JavaScript polyfill to implement the notification API.  See https://github.com/Haltroy/Korot/issues/22 for a previous discussion. Might not be the best example,  hopefully point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out